# MySQL will not start after relocating to external hard drive RPi

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to relocate a MySQL database from my Raspberry Pi to my external hard drive so that I can keep a larger database.
I know very little about this, so I apologize if this question is too simple, but these are the steps I have taken so far, as suggested on an RPi [forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=25978):

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
$ sudo mkdir /path/to/new/datadir
$ sudo cp -R /var/lib/mysql/mysql /path/to/new/datadir
$ sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
datadir = /path/to/new/datadir
$ sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /path/to/new/datadir
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Unfortunately, now I am getting an error when attempting to execute the last line (as shown above):

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

When I attempt to execute that last line, I get the following message:

```
[...] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed.
See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. failed!
```

I checked `journalctl -xn` and was told: `No journal files were found`.

`systemctl status mysql.service` yielded the following error:

```
mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
Active: failed(Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-02-26 22:15:08 ET; 4 min 4 sec ago
Process: 12923 ExecStop=/etc/init.d.mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 14171 ExecStart=/etc/init.d.mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Additional information: my filepath which I moved the active directory has a space in it, which is not enclosed by quotation marks. If I do put quotation marks around it, I fail at `Process 13627` instead.

Let me know if you have any suggestions-- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check for ownership of the copied datadir folder. make sure that it is owned by mysql user and group.

command to use:

```
ls -lah /path/to/copieddir
```

it should read something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 mysql mysql 4.0K Mar  8 15:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 50 root  root  4.0K Jan 20 14:50 ..
drwx------  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Nov  1 15:36 mysql
drwx------  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Nov  1 15:36 performance_schema
```

if you are seeing something this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 user user 4.0K Mar  8 15:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 50 root  root  4.0K Jan 20 14:50 ..
drwx------  2 user user 4.0K Nov  1 15:36 mysql
drwx------  2 user user 4.0K Nov  1 15:36 performance_schema
```

run this command:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /path/to/copieddir
```

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use ls with the long switch (-l) to show file/folder permissions:

```
ls -l /path/to/new/
```

Try 'man ls' for more details on the ls command and some further reading for you,  chmod and or chown will also be of interest.

Oh and Unix file permissions - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions